# Make a dataframe with artist, song and duration variables

Tags: r

I'm new with tidyverse in R.

I have a dataframe  `radio`,  from a radio channel, from a specfic date with variables: artist, song, duration.

My aim is to find which artist that has the most different songs playing on the choosen date.

```
 radio %>% select(artist, song) %>% arrange...
```

and then I'm lost. Please help if anyone is good at this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help people help you. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is also helpful to increase your chances of receiving a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `group_by` artist song and then compute the different songs:

```
radio %>% 
  select(artist, song) %>%
  group_by(artist) %>%
  summarise(n_song = n_distinct(song), .groups = "drop") %>%
  arrange(-n_song)
```